# Dynamic flat file creation using UNIX

Tags: file, unix, awk

I have a flat file "xxx.txt"

It contains various records

> aaaa
>
> bbbb
>
> cccc
>
> ...
>
> ......
> etc

My script must create multiple flat files in the name of each of these records(number of records may vary).

Like aaaa.txt, bbbb.txt,.....,etc...

Also, the text files must contain a message in all those files created,

Example:

> Hi,
>
> Welcome
>
> Thankyou

How to do this in shell script.

Note: In Unix SunOS 5.10(solaris)

Comment: I think you're almost there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "Hi\nWelcome\nThank you\n" > "${line}.txt"
done < file
```